# gridview rows and columns merge

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, c#-3.0

I am having the data in datatable with the below format that i am trying to bind to the  gridview  **(format -1)**

```
 Id     col1    col2
 20      a     ac-1
 20      a     ac-2
 20      a     ac-3
 20      a     ac-4
 21      a     ac-1
 21      a     ac-2
 21      a     ac-3
 21      a     ac-4
```

after had databound i am getting gridview in  below format **(format- 2)**

```
 Id     col1    col2
 20      a      ac-1
                ac-2
                ac-3
                ac-4
 21             ac-1
                ac-2
                ac-3
                ac-4
```

but I am looking for the below format of the data to be represent in gridview **(Format-3)**

```
   Id   col1    col2
   20     a     ac-1
                ac-2
                ac-3
                ac-4
   21     a     ac-1
                ac-2
                ac-3
                ac-4
```

and the below code is for Ondatabound event in grdiview

```
   for (int i = gvConversionGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
        GridViewRow row = gvConversionGrid.Rows[i];
        GridViewRow previousRow = gvConversionGrid.Rows[i - 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
            {
                if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                    }
                    row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Is there any way to manipulate the gridview and to bring the format for the gridview data like as in **format-3**..

Would any one please help on this one query that would be very grateful to me ..
Many thanks in advance

**Update** : I am looking for the below format image

[image]

Comment: is it not possible at all , would any one have any suggestions on this  merge rows ..

Comment: Is format 1 from one Table? and should it bind to only one GridView??

Comment: @Asif.Ali it is form single datatable only .... yes it is bind it to only one gridview ...

Comment: col1 value is same for all rows right and only Id and col2 are differs ?

Comment: @Asif.Ali sorry i could not get you col1 value is same for all rows means ?

Comment: I've found your problem's solution see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058443/how-to-show-a-listview-inside-a-gridview-controls-item-template Good Luck! :)

Comment: @Asif.Ali sorry that gridview is using listview inside .. here i  using only gridview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the previous `Id` value to a varable declared outside the method and compare the current row to that in the `OnRowDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
string previousCellValue = "";

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the dataitem back to a row
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check if the current id matches the previous row
        if (previousCellValue == row["Id"].ToString())
        {
            //clear the first cell
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "";

            //apply column span
            e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 2;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            previousCellValue = row["Id"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

UPDATE

```
string previousCellValue = "";
int previousCellCount = 1;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow and not the first row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the dataitem back to a row
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check if the current id matches the previous row
        if (previousCellValue == row["Id"].ToString())
        {
            //count the number of same cells
            previousCellCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            //span the rows for the first two cells
            if (previousCellCount > 1)
            {
                GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - previousCellCount].Cells[0].RowSpan = previousCellCount;
                GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - previousCellCount].Cells[1].RowSpan = previousCellCount;

                //hide the other cells in the column
                for (int i = 1; i < previousCellCount; i++)
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[(e.Row.RowIndex - previousCellCount) + i].Cells[0].Visible = false;
                    GridView1.Rows[(e.Row.RowIndex - previousCellCount) + i].Cells[1].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            previousCellValue = row["Id"].ToString();
            previousCellCount = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        //use the footer row to create spanning for the last rows if needed
        if (previousCellCount > 1)
        {
            GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - previousCellCount].Cells[0].RowSpan = previousCellCount;
            GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - previousCellCount].Cells[1].RowSpan = previousCellCount;

            //hide the other cells in the column
            for (int i = 1; i < previousCellCount; i++)
            {
                GridView1.Rows[(GridView1.Rows.Count - previousCellCount) + i].Cells[0].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Rows[(GridView1.Rows.Count - previousCellCount) + i].Cells[1].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i did that manipulation in onDataBound .. you have given the method in rowDataBound event right..

Comment: Yes, it is the OnRowDataBound event.

Comment: Still I am getting only single "a" in second column .. could you please suggest any changes has to be made

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. My snippet will produce the exact result as you indicated. See added screenshot.

Comment: i have attached image in my question , could you please suggest any changes to get that image kind of grid..

Comment: You need the values in the same cell? Not each in their own like in my example?

Comment: no .. sorry my bad I forgot to put the lines in that just updated the image could you please look into it ..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically you need some more complex code. You also need to repeat the rowspan code in the footer row to create spanning for the last row(s) if needed. PS this was more difficult that your [500 rep question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713671/insert-table-in-a-single-cell-inside-repeater) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could insert 2 hidden columns

```
 Id     col1    col2  groupindex  groupcount
 20      a     1      1         4
 20      a     2      2         4
 20      a     3      3         4
 20      a     4      4         4
 21      a     1      1         5
 21      a     2      2         5
 21      a     3      3         5
 21      a     4      4         5
 21      a     5      5         5
```

and set rowspan:

```
 void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {

        // set rowspan for the first row of group
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3]) == 1)
        {
            var rowSpan = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[4]);
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("rowspan", rowSpan);
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("rowspan", rowSpan);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion .. where do i need to insert that group Index and group count and how do i populate that into gridview ...